# Converting a str to a dict

Tags: python, sorting

I have a record in a field in the database with this format:

```
'(1, 7.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0), (4, 4.0), (5, 7.0), (6, 6.0), (7, 8.0), (8, 5.0)'
```

That comes as a string, I need to convert the 1st position to an `int` and the 2nd position to a `float`, then do something like this:

```py
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True))
```

and sort the results.

Any ideas on how to convert this `str` value into a `dict` so the final result looks like this?

```
OrderedDict([(7: 8.0), (5: 7.0), (1: 7.0), (6: 6.0), (8: 5.0), (4: 4.0), (3: 3.0), (2: 2.0)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract values:

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

s = '(1, 7.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0), (4, 4.0), (5, 7.0), (6, 6.0), (7, 8.0), (8, 5.0)'

d = OrderedDict()

result = re.findall(r'[-.0-9]+, [-.0-9]+', s)

for val in result:
    num = val.split(', ')
    first = int(num[0])
    second = float(num[1])
    d[first] = second
    
print(d) # OrderedDict([(1, 7.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0), (4, 4.0), (5, 7.0), (6, 6.0), (7, 8.0), (8, 5.0)])
```

Using `eval` is not safe, when you retrieving data from a database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'eval function' to evaulate your string data then you can use your tuple data to convert into dictionary data

str_val = '(1, 7.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 3.0), (4, 4.0), (5, 7.0), (6, 6.0), (7, 8.0), (8, 5.0)'

tuple_val = eval(str_val)

mydict = { x[0]:x[1] for x in tuple_val }

Comment: Are you sure? You can try it..

Comment: Ah you're right, just tested, my bad! You can do `mydict = dict(tuple_val)` btw.

Comment: Have a good day :)